# Perform semantic zooming using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, zooming, fabricjs

I want to achieve semantic zooming using fabricjs.

I've got a plot of dense points on the canvas. However, when we zoom in or zoom out, points size should remain as it is but the distance between them should increase or decrease respectively.

Take a look at these 2 examples

**Canvas Geometric Zooming**
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680958

**Canvas Semantic Zooming**
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3681006

I want to achieve zooming similar to Semantic zooming using fabricjs.

I've attempted the solution using fabricjs and so far seems to be working fine. I want to know or validate if there is any better way of achieving the same using fabricjs.

***We also want to preserve the point position relative to the image (floor plan), which is not happening. Please check the updated fiddle.***

My solution fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/bharatpatil/v7658dn9/43/

**HTML**

```
<button id="zoomIn">Zoom In</button>
<button id="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button>
<br>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
var i, dot,
  getRandomInt = fabric.util.getRandomInt,
  rainbow = ["#ffcc66", "#ccff66", "#66ccff", "#ff6fcf", "#ff6666"],
  rainbowEnd = rainbow.length - 1;

var circle1Radius = 20;

// create canvas instance
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  renderOnAddRemove: false
});


fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Sample_Floorplan.jpg', function(img) {

  img.scaleX = canvas2.width / img.width;
  img.scaleY = canvas2.height / img.height;
  img.set('selectable', false);
  img.opacity = 0.3;
  canvas2.add(img);

  createDots();
});


function createDots() {
  // draw random dots
  for (i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
    dot = new fabric.Circle({
      left: getRandomInt(0, 400),
      top: getRandomInt(0, 350),
      radius: circle1Radius,
      selectable: false,
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      lockRotation: true,
      hasControls: false,
      hasBorders: true,
      hasRotatingPoint: false,
      objectType: 'AppCircle'
    });
    dot.setGradient('fill', {
      type: 'radial',
      r1: 0,
      r2: circle1Radius,
      x1: circle1Radius,
      y1: circle1Radius,
      x2: circle1Radius,
      y2: circle1Radius,
      colorStops: {
        0: 'rgb(85, 196, 255, 1)',
        0.1: 'rgb(85, 196, 255, 0.5)',
        0.2: 'rgb(85, 196, 255, 0.4)',
        0.3: 'rgb(85, 196, 255, 0.3)',
        0.4: 'rgb(85, 196, 255, 0.2)',
        1: 'rgba(85, 196, 255, 0.1)',
      }
    });
    canvas2.add(dot);
  }
  canvas2.renderAll(); // Note, calling renderAll() is important in this case
}

function zoom(isZoomingIn) {
  var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.1;
  var objects = canvas2.getObjects();
  var dd = 1;
  if (isZoomingIn) dd = SCALE_FACTOR;
  if (!isZoomingIn) dd = 1 / SCALE_FACTOR;
  for (var i in objects) {
    if (objects[i].objectType !== 'AppCircle') {
      console.log(objects[i]);
      objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX * dd;
      objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY * dd;
    }
    objects[i].left = objects[i].left * dd;
    objects[i].top = objects[i].top * dd;
    objects[i].setCoords();
  }
  canvas2.setHeight(canvas2.height * dd);
  canvas2.setWidth(canvas2.width * dd);
  canvas2.renderAll();
  canvas2.calcOffset();
}

document.getElementById('zoomIn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  zoom(true);
});
document.getElementById('zoomOut').addEventListener('click', () => {
  zoom(false);
});
```

**Update**

We also want to preserve the point position relative to the image (floor plan), which is not happening. Please check the updated fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/bharatpatil/v7658dn9/43/